# How to show $\ln(\tan(x) + \sec(x))=\frac{\ln (1+\sin x )-\ln(1-\sin x )}{2}$ is true or false

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

￼$$\ln(\tan(x) + \sec(x))=\frac{\ln (1+\sin x )-\ln(1-\sin x )}{2}$$

Is this true or false? I thought the right side looked like a sum of an even and an odd function but I ended up with $$\ln(\tan(x) + \sec(x))=\ln(\tan(x) + \sec(x))$$ which is true, but it's not what I was trying to prove.

Comment: What is your question? What you want to prove?

Comment: The questions is true or false, does the left side equal the right side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll start from RHS
$$\begin{align}
\frac12\Big[\ln(1+\sin x )-\ln(1-\sin x)\Big]
&=\frac12\left[\ln\left(\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x} \right)\right]\\
&=\frac12\left[\ln\left(\frac{(1+\sin x)^2}{1-\sin^2 x} \right)\right]\\
&=\frac12\left[\ln\left(\frac{(1+\sin x)^2}{\cos^2 x} \right)\right]\\
&=\ln\left(\frac{ 1+\sin x }{\cos x} \right)\\
&=\ln\left(\frac1{\cos x}+\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}  \right)\\
\frac12\Big[\ln(1+\sin x )-\ln(1-\sin x)\Big]
&=\ln\left(\sec x+\tan x  \right)\\
\end{align}$$

So, It's true!

Answer (score 1):

$2\ln (\tan x+\sec x)=\ln \left(\dfrac{(1+\sin x)^2}{\cos^2 x}\right)=\ln \left(\dfrac{(1+\sin x)^2}{1-\sin^2 x}\right)=\ln \left(\dfrac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $s = \sin x, c = \cos x$.

The LHS is $\displaystyle \ln (\frac{s}{c} + \frac{1}{c}) = \ln (\frac{s+1}{c}) = \ln(\frac{1+s}{\sqrt{1-s^2}}) = \ln (\frac{1+s}{\sqrt{(1+s)(1-s)}}) \\ =\ln(\frac{\sqrt{1+s}}{\sqrt{1-s}}) = \ln(\sqrt{1+s}) - \ln(\sqrt{1-s}) = \frac{1}{2} [\ln(1+s) - \ln(1-s)]$

Comment: I have a bad repetitive strain injury of the right (dominant) wrist, which is why I need to use shorthand. Basically, did it in my head and typed it out slowly.